# Plot Data Points outside of Coordinate System using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with two variables and some data that is missing not at random.
I'd like to plot the correlation of the two variables including the datapoints that have NAs in one variable.

I have come up with one way:

- giving the NAs new values that are outside of the range of the original variable, so they are plotted at the right and top side of the plot
- using `geom_hline` & `geom_vline` to cut off those points.

  However, the axes continue, so ideally I would like the axes to stop at a certain cutoff point. 
  Is there a way to limit the axis but still plot points beyond the axes? 
  Or does someone have another idea how to display NAs because they are not missing at random?

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
a = c(runif(10))
b = c(runif(10))
data = as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
data$a[3] = NA
data$b[9] = NA

data$a[is.na(data$a)] = 1.3 #replacing NAs with high values
data$b[is.na(data$b)] = 1.3

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=a, y=b)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.2, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.2, linetype = "dashed")
p
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the plot]